# How Decript string previously cripted in BASH?

Tags: bash, passwords, crypt

i have a security problem on a script. I have to pass it a username and password, but i can't give it a password not crypted.
This script is writed in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=$1
USER=$2
PASSWORD=$3
#PASSWORD=`perl -e 'print pack "H*",$PASSWORD'`
wget -v $HOST --http-user=$USER --http-password=$PASSWORD --no-check-certificate
......
```

I have think to use something like this for generate cripted password:

```
perl -e 'print unpack "H*","yourpassword"'
```

and something like this for decript it

```
descrpt=`perl -e 'print pack "H*","encrypted password"'`
```

but it doesn't work. **Someone could help me please?**

Comment: I think you just supply the plain-text password, and `wget` will encrypt it as necessary when communicating with the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with:

echo $password | openssl enc -base64 -d

Answer (score 0):

Your command doesn't encrypt, it merely encodes the password as a hex string. Any programmer who sees the string will immediately know how to get the plaintext password back.

Instead, pass the password to `wget` in such a way that people can't just grab it from `ps` output. Here's one way of doing that:

```
wget -v "$HOST" --http-user="$USER" --no-check-certificate --config=/dev/stdin <<< "http_password = $PASSWORD"
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i need to give it, in my way, not by stdin, because it's the input for another compiled script

Comment: I don't understand. Are you not invoking wget?